# Read and write to same txt file in loop with StreamReader

Tags: powershell

I have a working script in PowerShell:

```
$file = Get-Content -Path HKEY_USERS.txt -Raw

foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("EXCLUDE_HKEY_USERS.txt"))
{
    $escapedLine = [Regex]::Escape($line)
    $pattern = $("(?sm)^$escapedLine.*?(?=^\[HKEY)")
    
    $file -replace $pattern, ' ' | Set-Content HKEY_USERS-filtered.txt
    $file = Get-Content -Path HKEY_USERS-filtered.txt -Raw
}
```

For each line in `EXCLUDE_HKEY_USERS.txt` it is performing some changes in file `HKEY_USERS.txt`. So with every loop iteration it is writing to this file and re-reading the same file to pull the changes. However, `Get-Content` is [notorious for memory leaks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4136066/powershell-does-not-release-the-memory), so I wanted to refactor it to  `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`, but I'm a having a hard time to make it work.

As soon as I do:

```
$filePath = 'HKEY_USERS-filtered.txt';
$sr = New-Object IO.StreamReader($filePath);
$sw = New-Object IO.StreamWriter($filePath);
```

I get:

```
New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "1" argument(s): "The process cannot access the file 
'HKEY_USERS-filtered.txt' because it is being used by another process."
```

So it looks like I cannot use StreamReader and StreamWriter on same file simultaneously. Or can I?

Comment: Note that `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines( )` is the way to go in this case. `Get-Content` without the `-Raw` switch doesn't lead to memory leaks it just adds, honestly uneeded, ETS properties to each line (each object of the file) that's why it's slow.

Comment: Adding to my previous comment, there is no performance difference between `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText( )` and `Get-Content -Raw`

Comment: As an aside: It's best to pseudo method syntax: Instead of `New-Object SomeType(arg1, ...)`, use `New-Object SomeType [-ArgumentList] arg1, ...` - PowerShell cmdlets, scripts and functions are invoked like _shell commands_, not like _methods_. That is, no parentheses around the argument list, and _whitespace_-separated arguments (`,` constructs an _array_ as a _single argument_, as needed for `-ArgumentList`). However, method syntax _is_ required if you use the PSv5+ `[SomeType]::new()` constructor-call method. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50636061/45375)

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon `ReadLines` indeed consumes much less memory than `Get-Content`, but it has a problem with [regexes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71544930/cannot-remove-text-between-two-strings-with-readlines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**tl;dr**

- `Get-Content -Raw` reads a file *as a whole* and is fast and consumes little unwanted memory.
- `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines()` is a faster and more memory-efficient alternative to line-by-line reading with `Get-Content` (without `-Raw`), but you need to ensure that the input file is passed as a *full* path, because .NET's working directory usually differs from PowerShell's.

  - [`Convert-Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/convert-path) resolves a given relative path to a full, file-system-native one.
  - A PowerShell-native alternative to using `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines()` is the [`switch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Switch) statement with the `-File` parameter, which performs similarly well while avoiding the working-directory discrepancy pitfall, and offers  additional features.
- There is no need to save the modified file content *to disk* after each iteration - just update the `$file` variable, and, after exiting the loop, save the value of `$file` to the output file.

```sh
$fileContent = Get-Content -Path HKEY_USERS.txt -Raw

# Be sure to specify a *full* path.
$excludeFile = Convert-Path -LiteralPath 'EXCLUDE_HKEY_USERS.txt'

foreach($line in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines($excludeFile)) {
    $escapedLine = [Regex]::Escape($line)
    $pattern = "(?sm)^$escapedLine.*?(?=^\[HKEY)"
    # Modify the content and save the result back to variable $fileContent
    $fileContent = $fileContent -replace $pattern, ' '
}

# After all modifications have been performed, save to the output file
$fileContent | Set-Content HKEY_USERS-filtered.txt
```

---

Building on [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon)'s helpful comments:

- [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) does *not* cause memory *leaks*, but it can consume a lot of memory that isn't garbage-collected until an unpredictable later point in time.

  - The reason is that - unless the `-Raw` switch is used - it decorates each line read with PowerShell [ETS (Extended Type System)](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/PowerShell-Docs/issues/6763) properties containing metadata about the file of origin, such as its path (`.PSPath`) and the line number (`.ReadCount`).
  - This both consumes extra memory and slows the command down - [GitHub issue #7537](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7537) asks for a way to *opt out* of this wasteful decoration, as it typically isn't needed.
  - However, reading with `-Raw` *is* efficient, because the entire file content is read into a *single, multi-line string*, which means that the decoration is only performed *once*.

> So it looks like I cannot use StreamReader and StreamWriter on same file simultaneously. Or can I?

No, you cannot. You cannot simultaneously read from a file and overwrite it.

To update / replace an existing file you have two options (note that, for a fully robust solution, all attributes of the original file (except the last write time and size) should be retained, which requires extra work):

- Read the old content into memory *in full*, perform the desired modification *in memory*, then write the modified content back to the original file, as shown in the top section.

  - There is a slight risk of data loss, however, namely if the process of writing back to the file gets interrupted.
- More safely, write the modified content to a *temporary* file and, upon successful completion, *replace* the original file with the temporary one.

Comment: For me `Get-Content` wastes 4+ GB of RAM (even with your code optimization), whereas `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines` at peak took only 1.5 GB RAM and memory was freed from PowerShell ISE process once the script stopped, which wasn't the case with `Get-Content`.

Comment: @van_folmert, you can't compare the two because `Get-Content -Raw` reads the _entire file_ into a single string as `[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText()` would - which you need, since you want to match across line boundaries. The memory isn't reclaimed until some time after the `$fileContent` variable goes out of scope or is manually removed. By contrast, `[System.IO.File]::ReadLines()` reads _line by line_, _lazily_ (as `Get-Content` without `-Raw` does _in the pipeline) with much more overhead), and in a loop the strings created may become eligible for garbage collection  after each iteration.