# Cannot remove text between two strings with ReadLines

Tags: regex, powershell

test.txt contents:

```
foo

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Microsoft]

bar

delete me!

[HKEY_other_key]

end-------------
```

[Online](https://regex101.com/r/jicJCw/1) regex matches the text to be removed correctly (starting from string `delete` until string `[HKEY`), but code written in PowerShell doesn't remove anything when I run it in PowerShell ISE:

```
$file = [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("test.txt")
$pattern = $("(?sm)^delete.*?(?=^\[HKEY)")
$file -replace $pattern, "" # returns original test.txt including line "delete me!" which should be removed
```

**It seems to be a problem with `ReadLines`** because when I use alternative `Get-Content`:

```
$file = Get-Content -Path test.txt -Raw
```

it removes the unwanted line correctly, but I don't want to use `Get-Content`.

Answer (score 4):

[`[System.IO.File]::ReadAllLines(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalllines?view=net-6.0) *reads all lines of the file into a **string array*** and you're using a multi-line regex pattern.

[`Get-Content -Raw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-7.2#example-6--get-raw-content) same as [`[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText(..)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=net-6.0), *reads all the text in the file into a **string***.

```sh
[System.IO.File]::ReadAllText("$pwd\test.txt") -replace "(?sm)^delete.*?(?=^\[HKEY)"
```

Results in:

```
foo

[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Microsoft]

bar

[HKEY_other_key]

end-------------
```

In case you **do need** to read the file *line-by-line* due to, for example, high memory consumption, [`switch -File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_switch?view=powershell-7.2) is an excellent built-in PowerShell alternative:

```sh
switch -Regex -File('test.txt') {
    '^delete' {        # if starts with `delete`
        $skip = $true  # set this var to `$true
        continue       # go to next line
    }
    '^\[HKEY' {        # if starts with `[HKEY`
        $skip = $false # set this var to `$false`
        $_             # output this line
        continue       # go to next line
    }
    { $skip } { continue } # if this var is `$true`, go next line
    Default   { $_ }       # if none of the previous conditions were met, ouput this line
}
```

Comment: `ReadAllText` works but it has about the same memory consumption that `Get-Content` had and hijacks memory after script is finished as well. `switch -Regex -File` seems to consume a bit less RAM but is very slow on a file with 650 000 lines (42 MB).

Comment: @van_folmert how is this related to the question?