# PowerShell script - escaping quotes in a csv file

Tags: powershell, escaping, quotes

I'm working with a script that opens up a csv, splits it into multiple smaller csvs than compresses the files so they can be easily uploaded.  The script does a fine job at this, but I need a way to escape double quotes (") so they are treated as text.  I've included the part of the script that does the splitting below.  Thanks!

```
param([string]$in_file, [string]$out_folder, [int]$linesperFile = 100000, [string]$ext = 'csv', [string]$header='Y', [string]$compress='Y')

Function Split-File{
    Param(
        $in_file,
        $out_folder,
        $linesperFile,
        $ext,
        $header
        )
    $filecount = 1
    $reader = $null
    $header_row = $null
    try{
        $reader = [io.file]::OpenText($in_file)
        if ($header -ne 'N') {
            $header_row = $reader.ReadLine()
        }
        try{
            $writer = [io.file]::CreateText("{0}{1}.{2}" -f ($out_folder,$filecount.ToString("000"),$ext))
            $filecount++
            $linecount = 0
            
            while($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true) {
                if ($header -eq 'Y') {
                    $writer.WriteLine($header_row)
                }
                while( ($linecount -lt $linesperFile) -and ($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true)){
                    $writer.WriteLine($reader.ReadLine());
                    $linecount++
                }
    
                if($reader.EndOfStream -ne $true) {
                    $writer.Dispose();
                    $writer = [io.file]::CreateText("{0}{1}.{2}" -f ($out_folder,$filecount.ToString("000"),$ext))
                    $filecount++
                    $linecount = 0
                }
            }
        } finally {
            $writer.Dispose();
        }
    } finally {
        $reader.Dispose();
    }
    return $filecount
```

I attempted iRon's solution and it still isn't working...  It reaches one of the lines with the double quotes and then just starts repeating the same line over and over.

[image]

The data below is supposed to be a single row of data
[image]

[image]

Comment: Why not using the [Convert*-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv) cmdlets and the [steppable pipeline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/mastering-the-steppable-pipeline/#the-steppable-pipeline)? See also: [Trouble Splitting a 9 GB csv file via Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75382747/1701026)

Comment: As an aside: it's better to represent Boolean values (`[bool]`) as `$true` and `$false`, and to implement Boolean _parameters_ as `[switch]`  parameters, where the presence of the switch (e.g., `-compress`) implies `$true`, and the absence `$false`.

Comment: @mklement0 The existence of double quotes in the csv is causing split at points it should not, stopping the current line/row of data immediately and continuing with that data on the next line which throws everything off.

Comment: So you're saying that some of your CSV data rows _span more than one line_, correct? If so, iRon's suggestion is the simplest solution, though it won't be fast. If you need a plain-text solution for performance: are _all_ fields quoted in the input file? If there are any field-internal `"` chars., how are they escaped? (`""` vs. ``\"``)

Comment: I meant CSV _source data_. On a general note, please (also) post your code, data, error messages as _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Comment: I suspect that your input `csv` isn't (**RFC 4180 and MIME standards**) valid by itself ([*Fields containing a line-break, double-quote or commas should be quoted. (If they are not, the file will likely be impossible to process correctly.)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and likely also fails on other applications as Excel. Please add an example of the record/line with the concerned double quotes that is failing to the question.

Comment: @iRon OP Updated

Comment: Please provide a minimal sample of the CSV _source data_, as _text_.

Comment: Please, [DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557), see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Besides, the last image already suggests that the input data is a correct formatted `csv` (e.g. what is the meaning of the double quote in the lower left cell???)