# Powershell - Get IP Addresses for hostnames from File (more than 150K hostnames)

Tags: powershell, ip, export-to-csv, hostname

My code:

```
$Servers = Get-Content -Path "./FULl_List_hosts_all_CSV_V2.txt"
$Array = foreach($Server in $Servers) {
    $Server = $Server.Trim()
    try {
        $DNSCheck = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($Server)
        # just output an object so it gets collected in variable $Array
        [PsCustomObject]@{ 
            'Server name' = $Server  # or $DNSCheck.HostName
            'IP Address'  = ($DNSCheck.AddressList | Where-Object {$_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork'})[0].IPAddressToString
        }
    }
    catch {
        # either do nothing here to skip this server of output a 'n/a' object
        [PsCustomObject]@{ 
            'Server name' = $Server
            'IP Address'  = 'n/a'
        }
    }
}

# output on screen
$Array | Format-Table -AutoSize

# write to csv
$Array | Export-Csv -Path "./pingstatus.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

The Full_List_Hosts has more than 150K hostnames. When I run the shell script it sits there. No doubt loading it all - but is there a way I can make it count up to maybe 200 then pause, write to the csv file then continue?
If I do a shorter file - the script takes seconds to complete.
Just want to make sure it is truly running.
OPen to recomendations.
thanks

I tried using a shorter list of hosts in a file. worked fine.
I want some indicaton that it is running and not just sitting there with a "dumb look" only to come after HOURS of running and find nothing.

Comment: How about using a progress bar inside your loop?  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: Have a look at `Write-Progress`.

Comment: Your code would benefit a lot from multithreading, `[System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry(...)` is slowing you down. If you have pwsh 7+ you can use `ForEcach-Object -Parallel` then pipe directly the output to `Export-Csv`

Answer (score 1):

Just use the [PowerShell pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines) the way it is designed:

```
Get-Content -Path "./FULl_List_hosts_all_CSV_V2.txt" | Foreach-Object {
    $Server = $_.Trim()
    $Output = try {
        $DNSCheck = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostEntry($Server)
        # just output an object so it gets collected in variable $Array
        [PsCustomObject]@{ 
            'Server name' = $Server  # or $DNSCheck.HostName
            'IP Address'  = ($DNSCheck.AddressList | Where-Object {$_.AddressFamily -eq 'InterNetwork'})[0].IPAddressToString
        }
    }
    catch {
        # either do nothing here to skip this server of output a 'n/a' object
        [PsCustomObject]@{ 
            'Server name' = $Server
            'IP Address'  = 'n/a'
        }
    }
    $Output | Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-Host
    $Output
} | Export-Csv -Path "./pingstatus.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

A more advanced solution (that also supports batches) would be using the steppable pipeline, see e.g.: [Trouble Splitting a 9 GB csv file via Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75382747/1701026)

Comment: It looks like pipelines are as fast as ReadLines. I didn't realize that. I'll make a note of it. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You can process the file line by line. It will be much faster. And the result of each server check will be visible immediately.

```
foreach($server in [System.IO.File]::ReadLines("C:\path\to\FULl_List_hosts_all_CSV_V2.txt"))
{
   ...
   $result = [PsCustomObject]@{ ... }
   Write-Output $result
   $result | Export-Csv -Path "./pingstatus.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
}
```

Comment: [Wrapping the `Export-Csv ` cmdlet is quiet expensive](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations#avoid-wrapping-cmdlet-pipelines) for a 150K job, and therefore should go outside the loop.